# Finding maximum likelihood solution of a continuous state HMM

Tags: maximum-likelihood, gradient-descent, hidden-markov-model

The likelihood of a hidden Markov model (HMM) for states $x_0, \dots, x_N$ and observations $y_1, \dots, y_N$ can be written as

$$ L = f(x_0) \prod_{i=1}^N f(y_i | x_i) f(x_i | x_{i-1} )$$

where we use $f(\cdot)$ to represent a pdf.

If the states $x_0, \dots, x_N$ can only take values from a discrete set, then we can find the most likely sequence of states using the [Viterbi algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viterbi_algorithm).

My question is then, what is this the best way to go about the optimisation in the continuous case?

**Note**

If the states take values on a continuous set, then we could use gradient descent for example to try to estimate the most likely sequence of states.

However if $N$ is very large, it could take a long time to calculate the gradient of $L$. We may be able to perform stochastic gradient descent but I feel we would not want to re-order the observations $i$, as you would between batches of standard gradient descent. Therefore I am unsure how well this would work.

Comment: I believe there is no closed formula from looking into it, but I could be wrong. The prior and transition distributions are multivariate normal (which is nice), however the observation distribution is essentially a neural network with a softmax output layer.

As I said, I couldn't find a closed-form expression for the smoothing density, however all the distributions are differentiable and so is the likelihood and log likelihood.

Answer (score 2):

One approach is to make an assumption that your states, i.e., $x_i$ evolve from a Gaussian distribution. For example,
\begin{align}
x_{i} = F x_{i-1} + e_i
\end{align}
where $e_i \sim \mathcal{N}(0,Q)$ and $Q$ is a known covariance matrix. Since $x_i$ takes only discrete set, you can make an assumption that the entries of the covariance matrix $Q$ are very small (of the magnitude 1e-12). This implies that $f(x_i|x_{i-1})$ follows a Gaussian distribution. Now, we can write one-step prediction density as
\begin{align}
x_{i|i-1} &= F x_{i-1|i-1}  \\
P_{i|i-1} &= F P_{i-1|i-1} F^T + Q
\end{align}
where $x_{i|i-1}$ and $P_{i|i-1}$ are the mean and covariance of the prediction density. If you know the likelihood expression of $f(y_i|x_i)$, i.e., $L(x_i|y_i)$, expand it using Taylor series expansion about a point $\hat{x}_i$. For example,
\begin{align}
L(x_i|y_i) &\approx L(\hat{x}_i|y_i) + L'(\hat{x}_i|y_i)(x_i - \hat{x}_i) + \frac{1}{2} (x_i - \hat{x}_i)^T L''(\hat{x}_i|y_i) (x_i - \hat{x}_i) \\
           &= \frac{1}{2}[x_i - \{ \hat{x}_i - (L''(\hat{x}_i|y_i))^{-1}L'(\hat{x}_i|y_i) \}]^T L''(\hat{x}_i|y_i) [x_i - \{ \hat{x}_i - (L''(\hat{x}_i|y_i))^{-1}L'(\hat{x}_i|y_i) \}]
\end{align}
Therefore, the expression takes the form of a Gaussian distribution where the mean and variance of the posterior density are given as
\begin{align}
x_{i|i} &= \{ \hat{x}_i - (L''(\hat{x}_i|y_i))^{-1}L'(\hat{x}_i|y_i) \} \\
P_{i|i} &= [L''(\hat{x}_i|y_i)]^{-1}
\end{align}
Note that in the above formulation we make an assumption that the Hessian is always invertible. The point $\hat{x}_i$ is generally the mean value of the distribution $f(x_i|x_{i-1})$.

Comment: Very interestingly, the update equations you gave are the way I've been currently been doing things, although I came about them a slightly different way. The issue is that I believe for my problem the Taylor series approximation may not be very good and the given method compounds this at each time step. This is why I was asking about a continuous optimisation approach to finding the maximum likelihood states.

Comment: How about drawing the state from a mixture of Gaussian distributions where the weights of the distribution are to be found by minimizing a cost function (perhaps, a LASSO-like cost function, which applies sparsity on the weights).

Comment: I'm not sure I entirely understand, do you mean approximating the posterior at each time step by a mixture of Gaussians instead of just a single Gaussian distribution?